# iframe loading problem in the jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, iframe

```
<head>
<TITLE> Sample CIM Implementation </TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function init(){
            document.forms[0].submit();
      }
</script>

</head>
<BODY onload="init()">

<iframe id="authpopup" src="https://test.authorize.net/profile/manage">

</iframe>

<form type ="hidden" method="post" name="iframepopup"  id="formAuthorizeNetPage" style="display:none;">
      <input type="hidden" name="Token" value="<%=token%>"/>
</form>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

i have a jsp page in which iam loading a iframe. The iframe is getting refreshed continuolusly i actually don want the iframe to get refreshed. This seems to flicker

Comment: Why are you submitting the form on load? What's the functional requirement?

Answer (score 4):

As soon as the page loads, you call `init()`, which submits a form. This causes the page containing the iframe to reload, and thus also causes the iframe to reload. The page then calls `init()` again (since it has just reloaded) and so on.

Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks but where do you want me to place the iframe can u be more specific

Comment: I said "Don't call `init()`". I said nothing about putting an iframe anywhere.

Comment: then where the init() should be called

Comment: Nowhere. All it does is submit a form to the current page. The only bit of data that form has in it comes from the current page, so there is no need to submit the information as the server already has it.